# Wrong Sorting nomenclature and predefined variables

Tags: nomenclature

this time I'm writing my Bachelor Thesis on Uni Stuttgart. Now I got a Problem. I predefined my Variables for being able to change them easily in the whole dokument. For example I did it like this:
`\newcommand{\x}{L_i}`
If I now create a list of variables by `\makenomenclature` the variables are sorted by the command. Here \x. Is it possible to sort it by the given variables? Here L_i.
It would be very nice to have a most possible easy solution for this.
Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A short example of what you're doing would help in helping you. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228

Comment: Nice catch, @Mike.